# Fabric8 2.1.1 doesn't work as expected under OpenShift V3

Tags: openshift-origin, fabric8

I am trying to install fabric8 with some small modification in hope to achieve latest Openshift 0.5.1 and Fabric8 2.1.1 automatically.
Installation completed successfully and I am able to open openshift and hawtio screen. 
However, when I try to connect to one of the container, the pop up new tab appear but won't redirect me. It prompt me for password but then will just open new tab and stop there. For example, the URL will stop at "http://fabricdev.mydomain.com/?con=app-library-controller-5e0gx"

I have try to open few docker log but unable to understand further. Any help will be very appreciated.

Here is my modified file:

[Get Fabric8](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d21dw7guto3ikx/get-fabric8.sh?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the web console to connect to JVMs.

Roland Fuss found that same issue as well and reported it here
https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/4033

He also found a workaround with jolokia, that we have applied to our
quickstarts which will be in the next release 2.1.6.
https://github.com/fabric8io/quickstarts/issues/431

You can try to apply the same workaround in your current environment -
hopefully that would work.

And when the root problem is fixed in kubernetes / openshift then we
can remove the workaround and it all work as before.